# Isekai where man proposes to women with a dagger and he had no idea what it means

Tags: story-identification, manga

This is what I do remember about this manga. I read it I would say about a year ago. The Main character I believe is transported to another world. He goes and registers as an adventurer and meets a woman (I believe he helps her). For his kindness she takes him to a restaurant, and she orders food that I believe was a type of aphrodisiac. They end up have relations that night and the next day she tells him that she needs his help. It turns out that she is a princess of a country and needs him to help her do something.

Later on he goes to a weapon shop and sees a black dagger, I believe made of obsidian, and gives it to this girl. It turns out that in this world giving someone a dagger like that means you ask them for their hand in marriage. Because he was from another world, he had no idea and thus when he found out he asks her for the dagger back and she is heartbroken. But then he actually proposes to her, and she accepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be *[A 29-Year-Old Bachelor, Transported To A New World To Live Freely... At Least He Wanted To](https://myanimelist.net/manga/120857/29-sai_Dokushin_wa_Isekai_de_Jiyuu_ni_Ikitakatta)* as per its entry in [Accidental Proposal](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AccidentalProposal) on TV Tropes:

[image: Front cover of A 29-Year-Old Bachelor, Transported To A New World To Live Freely... At Least He Wanted To]

> After making a lot of money on an unexpectedly dangerous quest that also brought them closer together, isekai protagonist Taishi takes his teammate-turned-lover Marle shopping for better gear. He notices her admiring an expensive mythril shortsword, and ends up buying it for her while she's distracted. Later that day, during a date, he presents it to her, and although she's hesitant to take it at first, after a little convincing, she happily accepts it, and Taishi is surprised when the people nearby start applauding and congratulating them. When they return to their inn, the innkeeper's wife spots it and recalls when her husband gave her a mythril shortsword, prompting Taishi to ask if gifting a mythril shortsword has any special meaning. After a bit of stunned silence, Marle starts crying. Taishi has been hiding the fact that he was actually summoned from another world, and this is his first time hearing that in this world, it's common knowledge that when a man gives a mythril sword or dagger to a woman, he's promising to keep her safe if she'll agree to belong to him alone. After returning to their room, Taishi gently explains that he didn't realize he was proposing marriage so it didn't count, then devastates her by taking the mythril shortsword out of her hands... and presents it to her again.